# I set the service data,but after $http done, I cannot get the service data

Tags: angularjs

My service define like this:

```
module.factory('portfolio',function(){
var data;
var selectedPort;
return{
    getData: function(){
        return data;
    },
    setData:function(portfolios){
        data = portfolios;
    },
    getSelectedPort:function(){
        return selectedPort;
    },
    setSelectedPort:function(portfolioDetail){
        selectedPort = portfolioDetail;
    }
}
});
```

And in my controller the code as follows:

```
module.controller('portfoliosController', function($scope,$http, alertService,stockService, userDataService, portfolio){

var req = {
     method: 'get',
     url: 'www.facebook.com',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': userDataService.getToken()
     }
};
$http(req).then(function(reponse){
    $scope.portfoliosPriceList = reponse['data'];  
    portfolio.setData($scope.portfoliosPriceList);  
    console.log(portfolio.getData())//At here,I can get the portfolio's data

}, function(){
    alertService.setMessge("System maintenance , please try again later");
    alertService.alert();
});
console.log(portfolio.getData())//At here, I cannot get the portfolio's data
});
```

the error is

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'message.substr')
```

Anybody can help me to solve this problem?Actually, I really do not understand, why I cannot get the data outside the $http

Comment: its because $http call hasnt finished by the time the console.log() is called.what do you want to do with the data??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request that you do with the `$http` service is done asynchronously, so the callback that you pass to the `.send` is not immediately invoked.

The code that follows (the `console.log`) is executed just after the `$http(req)` call is made but before the callback is called when the request is responded.

Maybe you will understand better with an simpler example:

```js
function portfoliosController() {
    
  var data = 'Initial Data. ',
      content = document.getElementById('content');

  // setTimeout would be your $http.send(req)
  // calledLater would be your .then(function() { ... })
  setTimeout(function calledLater() {
    data = 'Data coming from the server takes some time to arrive...';
    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + data;
  }, 1000);

  content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + data;
}

portfoliosController();
```

```html
<div id="content">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because javascript is asynchronous, so the code:

```
portfolio.getData()
```

Is maybe executing before the data is returned from the service.

In this case, you should only use the data of the portfolio just after the request is complete (inside the .then() function of $http) or put a promise.

Here is the documentation for angular promises:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q